# How to set the dynamixel motors to multi-turn mode

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use dynamixel MX-106 in ROS, and I want to use it in multi-turn mode.
I could find the way to set it to multi-turn mode in operating manual which can be found in web page of Robotis.
But I can not figure out how to do it in ROS. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232570/how-to-set-the-dynamixel-motors-to-multi-turn-mode./) by [Kaz-Kom](https://answers.ros.org/users/26668/kaz-kom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-04-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Kaz-Kom, did you get  the solution for this problem i.e. controlling  Dynamixel motors for multi-turns.

I followed the steps as described in below link:
http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/CreatingAMultiTurnJointController

This is what I did :

- Changed the Operating mode (Register number 11) to 4 instead of  3 (default).
- Changed the angle limit from 0 to 8192

But still I am not  able to set the multi-turns.
Can somebody let me know what extra changes I have to do to enable multi-turns.

---

Originally posted by [saurabh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28038/saurabh/) with karma: 73 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saurabh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28038/saurabh/) on 2017-12-06**:
I solved this problem by Factory reset the motor and updating DXL_OPERATING_MODE register before updating DXL_TORQUE_ENABLE register to '1', as DXL_OPERATING_MODE is an EEPROM register and it  has to be updated, before updating DXL_TORQUE_ENABLE register.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-02**:
@sakuraba Please don't use an answer to ask a question. This isn't a forum. You can ask a new question and reference this question.